# Different item template for each item in a WPF List?

Tags: wpf, itemtemplate

I have many items inside a list control. I want each item to have a different item template depending on the type of the item. So the first item in the list is a ObjectA type and so I want it to be rendered with ItemTemplateA. Second item is a ObjectB type and so I want it to have ItemTemplateB for rendering. At the moment I can only use the ItemTemplate setting to define one template for them all. Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

the `ItemTemplateSelector` will work but I think it is easier to create multiple `DataTemplate`s in your resource section and then just giving each one a `DataType`. This will automatically then use this `DataTemplate` if the items generator detects the matching data type?

```
<DataTemplate DataType={x:Type local:ObjectA}>
   ...
</DataTemplate>
```

Also make sure that you have no `x:Key` set for the `DataTemplate`.
Read more about this approach [here](http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/361#.Us6JPJG-3nc)

Comment: I forgot to put in the {x:Type... stuff, please try again!

Comment: Also make sure that you have no x:Key set!

Comment: it seems the link is dead.. Do you have any similar source to refer to?

Comment: The quotes around {x:Type local:Object} are missing. And here is a [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31837/Creating-an-Internationalized-Wizard-in-WPF) to a similar solution with ItemsControl and DataType binding in WPF.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the [ItemTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector.aspx) property of your list control. You can point it to a custom TemplateSelector and decide which template to use in code.

Here's a blog post describing TemplateSelectors:

http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/johnbowen/archive/2007/06/21/20463.aspx

Edit: Here's a better post:

http://blog.paranoidferret.com/index.php/2008/07/16/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector/