# Loading UserControl to the region of the Window on ComboBox change

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have got ComboBox which is populated with collection of customTypes. On comboBox change, I would like to load/change content in the particular region so that it loads related data for the selected ComboBox item (it could be in the form of loading userControl or I i dont mind specifying DataTemplate for it).

It is similar to this question [WPF Load Control question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164738/wpf-load-control-question). But in this question, he is talking about individual DataTemplates in the actual Listbox, while I am talking about populating certain window region on ComboBox change.

I am using MVVM (and not PRISM) .Net 3.5.

Comment: So basically you would change Model which will be displayed, not only an UI layout?

Comment: @sll, model will stay as is, but data might be displayed/represented differently depending on the option user chooses from ComboBox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U could use `ContentControl` which is the placeholder for the actual `Content` that is dynamically decided as per combobox selection.

**The follwoing code is just for guidance**

```
<Window ...>

   <Window.Resources>
       <MyView1 x:Key="MyView1" />
       <MyView2 x:Key="MyView2" />
   </Window.Resources>  

   ...

   <ComboBox x:Name="MyCombo">
       <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
           <sys:String>"MyView1"</sys:String>
           <sys:String>"MyView2"</sys:String>
           ....
       </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
   </ComboBox>

   ... 

   <!-- This is where your region is loaded -->
   <ContentControl>
       <ContentControl.Style>
           <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
               <Style.Triggers>
                   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedItem,
                                                  ElementName=MyCombo}"
                                Value="MyView1">
                        <Setter Property="Content"
                                Value="{StaticResource MyView1}"
                   </DataTrigger>
                   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedItem,
                                                  ElementName=MyCombo}"
                                Value="MyView2">
                        <Setter Property="Content"
                                Value="{StaticResource MyView2}"
                   </DataTrigger>
               </Style.Triggers>
           </Style>
       </ContentControl.Style>
   </ContentControl> 
</Window>
```

The data loading can be part of the `MyView1` and `MyView2` user control's constructor or your main UI's data context view model.

Comment: tnx @AngelWPF, trying it out now, will let you know if/when it works

Comment: it is possible to have default View ? as user can put/enter value that is not in the ComboBox, is it possible to provide default content/view for this ? (so that it will failover to that if no existing options in the combobox are selecteD)

Comment: For that DataTrigger should be checked for (x:Null} value.... <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=MyCombo}" Value="{x:Null}" ....>

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the question is how to change underlying data being bound to UI and not a DataTemplate only.

You can use `EventSetter` which will be handled in code behind where you can switch DataContext for a region you've mentioned:

```
<ComboBox>
     <ComboBox.Resources>         
         <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">             
           <EventSetter Event="Selector.SelectionChanged"
                        Handler="YourHandler"/>         
         </Style>     
     </ComboBox.Resources> 
</ComboBox>
```

But from MVVM perspectives it could be not perfect solution so you can introduce your own ComboBox class wich is Command aware, see this SO post: [WPF command support in ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222430/wpf-command-support-in-combobox)

In this way you can decouple logic from UI using Command.

Comment: Tnx for your answer +1, it is actualling related to just changing the UI.